# How to fix the beamer and amsthm conflict?

Tags: beamer, amsthm

I want to have a style of `Theorem 1`, and the next one is `Theorem 1'` with the help of Amsthm package.

The following code seems alright, but can't be compiled:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newtheorem{mthm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\themthm}{\ref{thm:1}'}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:1}
  test
  \end{thm}
  \begin{mthm}
    test
  \end{mthm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The err. log is :

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname
l.16 \end{frame}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname
l.16 \end{frame}
```

I find the err cased by the `\renewcommand{\themthm}{\ref{thm:1}'}` line but how to fix this?

Comment: Could you detail more about your original aim?

Comment: It isn't a beamer/amsthm conflict it is simply an error in the definition. For a latex counter `mthm` the command `\themthm` has to _expand_ to the print form of the counter.

Comment: So how to fix this?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I updated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First possibility: non-shared counters

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{mthm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\themthm}{\arabic{mthm}'}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:1}
  test
  \end{thm}
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:2}
  test
  \end{thm}
  \begin{mthm}
    test
  \end{mthm}
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:3}
  test
  \end{thm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

### Second possibility: shared counters

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{mthm}[thm]{Theorem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{mthm}{\addtocounter{thm}{-1}\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}'}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:1}
  test
  \end{thm}
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:2}
  test
  \end{thm}
  \begin{mthm}
    test
  \end{mthm}
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:3}
  test
  \end{thm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

`amsthm` is not needed, but loading it, it doesn't cause any conflict.